# Hibernate application in Eclipse am geting this error when running main method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException:     
com.hibernate.config.hibernate.cfg.xml not found    at 
org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)  at 
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2176)    at 
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2157)  at 
com.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)   at 
com.hibernate.dao.StudentDAOImpl.insertStudent(StudentDAOImpl.java:14)  at 
Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Why this error comes ? Can anybody point me out whats wrong I did ?

Comment: Can you tell us what your project structure looks like please.

Comment: Where is your config file located ? Are you using any build tool like Maven or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate XML configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml` is always put at the root of your project classpath, outside of any package. If you place this configuration file into a different directory, you may encounter the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException:     
com.hibernate.config.hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

To tell Hibernate to look for `hibernate.cfg.xml` into other directory, you need to modify the default Hibernate's `SessionFactory` class by passing your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file path as an argument into the `configure()` method:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
    .configure("/path to file/hibernate.cfg.xml")
    .buildSessionFactory();

return sessionFactory;
```

**Using Maven :**

With maven your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file should be in `src/main/resources`. If you placed it in `src` folder then it will not available to your CLASSPATH at runtime.

Since you are using Eclipse, make sure that `src/main/resources` folder is in your build path configuration in project preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The path to hibernate config file that you specify in the session factory creation should be **relative to classpath.**
So, if you classes when the get compiled go into build directory, then your path to config xml should be relative to that path.